# Change default font numeral format

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I am using a font I like in a program that doesn't have access to all opentype features so I get no choice as to how numerals are displayed. By default they are old style where I'd rather them appear lining and (ideally) tabular

Can I use font-forge to apply the 'lnum' substitution lookup by default or apply them directly to the font and then export? If so, how? Or is there another free alternative?

I had some luck simply copy/pasting over the standard numerals before exporting but in certain instances things come out strange and I feel I'm probably just hacking at something that probably has a proper method.

Before I get asked: Yes the font license allows modification as long as the name is changed (which I shall do).